# Facebook SDK Single Friend selection with

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, kotlin, facebook-sdk-4.0

My mobile app uses Facebook SDK for authentication and users can invite one of their facebook friends who installed the app.

One approach is makeing a GraphRequest to /me/friends and showing a new ativity with a RecyclerView.I didn't want to implement my own custom picker so tried to make the invitation over Game Request.

```
root.show_friends_button.setOnClickListener {

            val content = GameRequestContent.Builder().
                    setFilters(GameRequestContent.Filters.APP_USERS).
                    setMessage("Come play this level with me").
                    setActionType(GameRequestContent.ActionType.TURN).setTitle("I bet you!").build();


            requestDialog = GameRequestDialog(this)
            requestDialog!!.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                    object : FacebookCallback<GameRequestDialog.Result> {
                        override fun onSuccess(result: GameRequestDialog.Result) {
                            val participants = result.requestRecipients
                            val id = result.requestId
                        }

                        override fun onCancel() {}
                        override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {}
                    }

            )
            requestDialog!!.show(content)
        }
```

The problem here is that you can choose up to 50 friends from the pop up dialog.Is there a way to limit this to single user?